# How to disable eclipse annotation error

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse, I get the following errors in my project:

> The annotation `@SuppressWarnings` is disallowed for this location

Can you please tell me how can I turn those errors into warnings?

Thank you.

---

Look like it is a bug in `eclipse3.6M5`. This is the code which gives me error. But it works fine in `eclipse3.6M4`.

```
package java.lang.annotation;

/**
 * Defines a meta-annotation for indicating that an annotation is automatically
 * inherited.
 *
 * @since 1.5
 */
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Inherited {
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some context. When do you use the SuppressWarnings annotation? It is allowed before one of the following Type,Field,Method,Parameter,Constructor and local variable. All other locations are errors.

Comment: How does your added example match to your initial question? Does this code give you the error message?

Comment: The added example is the code causing the problem in eclipse 3.6M5. But the same project is fine in eclipse 3.6M4.

Answer (score 2):

If it's really a wrong location of the `@SuppressWarnings` then there is not much you can do. But why should you turn that off?

As any annotation you can use `@SuppressWarnings` only in front of a class, a variable declaration, a parameter or a method declaration. All other locations will give you a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings.

- Choose Annotations.
- Change "Unhandled token in '@SuppressWarnings':" to Ignore.

Rebuild your project and this irritant will go away. Dirty - but given that this masks other issues in the project and waists time probably worth the time saved.